# Silverlight MVVM:Updating parent view model based on status of child View model

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I am new to Silverlight MVVM.
I have one requirement to show checkbox in a parent child hierarchy.
While loading the page if the child is checked then parent checkbox should also get checked.

I have created a ViewModel as below

```
   public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
  private string name;
        private string percent;
        private bool isChecked;
        internal event EventHandler CheckboxStateChanged = delegate { };

        private List<TestViewModel> testViewModel;

        public List<TestViewModel> TestViewModel1
        {
            get { return testViewModel; }
            set
            {
                testViewModel = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TestViewModel1");

            }
        }

        public TestViewModel()
        {
            //IsChecked = true;
            //Name = "Hello";
            //Percent = "10";
        }

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return isChecked; }
            set
            {
                isChecked = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
                               CheckboxStateChanged(this, new EventArgs());

            }
        }


     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }

}
```

In my main.xaml.cs I have created recursive method which will create the parent child hierarchy of checkboxes.
On clicking the child checkbox, parent checkbox is getting checked as I have added eventhandler in my VM (CheckboxStateChanged ) for that.But while on page load if child is checked then parent also get checked,I am unable to do that..Pls help.

Note I can not make parents checked until I get the status of child and once I get child status m not sure how to go back to parent.

Parent VM contains list of same VM as children(i.e public List TestViewModel1)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct you are looking for a way to bouble up checkbox values from the children to its parent checkbox.

I've done a similar solution for a tree view. This code works but needs some event detaching if the collection changes.

The following is the set of classes that is used to run the ViewModel part of this solution.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class StructureViewModel : ViewModelBase
{        
    private bool? _isChecked = false;

    public bool? IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (_isChecked != value)
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");                    
            }
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }        
}

public class ChildViewModel : StructureViewModel
{

}

public class ParentViewModel : StructureViewModel
{
    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        Children = new List<ChildViewModel>();                    
    }

    public ICollection<ChildViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Parents = new List<ParentViewModel>();

        var parent = new ParentViewModel { Name = "Parent" };

        parent.Children.Add(new ChildViewModel
        {
            Name = "Child1"                
        });

        parent.Children.Add(new ChildViewModel
        {
            Name = "Child2"
        });

        Parents.Add(parent);
    }

    public ICollection<ParentViewModel> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

To display this I use the following markup:

```
     <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Name}">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <local:CheckParentBehavior Children="{Binding Children}" />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </CheckBox>

            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

The magic that fixes the checkboxes are the CheckParentBehavior:

```
public class CheckParentBehavior : Behavior<CheckBox>
{
    public IEnumerable<StructureViewModel> Children
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<StructureViewModel>)GetValue(ChildrenProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ChildrenProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildrenProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Children", typeof(IEnumerable<StructureViewModel>), typeof(CheckParentBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(OnChildrenChanged));

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        if (Children != null)
            AssociatedObject.IsChecked = GetCheck(Children);
    }

    private static void OnChildrenChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            foreach (var child in e.NewValue as IEnumerable<StructureViewModel>)
                child.PropertyChanged += (_, args) => OnChildPropertyChanged(d as CheckParentBehavior, args);
        }
    }

    private static void OnChildPropertyChanged(CheckParentBehavior behavior, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.PropertyName == "IsChecked")
            behavior.AssociatedObject.IsChecked = GetCheck(behavior.Children);
    }

    public static bool? GetCheck(IEnumerable<StructureViewModel> children)
    {
        if (children.All(c => c.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault()))
            return true;
        else if (children.Any(c => c.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault()))
            return null;
        else
            return false;
    }


}
```

What happens is that it listens to each childs propertychanged event and if it changes the ischecked property it will change the parents accordingly.

Hopefully you can use some of this code to solve your problem.

Comment: You can ofc do this in the ViewModel logic as well but the above Beahvior can be reused if the "IsChecked" property name is configurable.